# Date and Time Calculation excluding weekends

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula, date

I want to figure out the amount of time between Quote Start Date and Quote Complete Time in minutes and exclude weekends. I have tried several examples I found online but I always get a syntax error.

Does anyone know what I need to modify?

I am in Office 365 with SharePoint.

```
=IF(Quote Start Date<>"",IF(Quote Complete Time<>"",IF(AND((WEEKDAY(Quote Complete Time,2))<(WEEKDAY([Quote Start Date],2)),((WEEKDAY(Quote Start Date[],2))-(WEEKDAY([Quote Complete Time],2)))>1),(((DATEDIF([Quote Start Date],[Quote Complete Time],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Quote Start Date],[Quote Complete Time],"D"))/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF([Quote Start Date],[Quote Complete Time],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Quote Start Date],[Quote Complete Time],"D"))/7,1)*2))),IF(AND((WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2))<(WEEKDAY([Quote Start Date],2)),((WEEKDAY([Quote Start Date,2))-(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)))>1),(((DATEDIF(][Quote Start Date,TODAY(),"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(][Quote Start Date],TODAY(),"D")+1)/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF([Quote Start Date],TODAY(),"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Quote Start Date],TODAY(),"D")+1)/7,1)*2)))),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Start Date]),ISBLANK([End Date])),"",IF(AND((WEEKDAY([End Date],2))<(WEEKDAY([Start Date],2)),((WEEKDAY([Start Date],2))-(WEEKDAY([End Date],2)))>1),(((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D"))/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D"))/7,1)*2)))&" days, "&TEXT(MOD([End Date]-[Start Date],1),"hh "" hrs, "" mm "" mins"""))
```

I can get the time interval between two days excluding weekends.
[image]